# Make iOS table view cell maximum height where no scrolling is required

Tags: ios, tableview

I have an grouped table view in iOS with 2 static cells and the first cell has a static height. I want to make height of the second cell maximum without scrolling is required for the table view. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you using a tableView for this? UIView with subViews and constraints will be easier and encumber you less with unintended consequences?

Answer (score 0):

Try the contentSize method, used to calculate the table’s layout.

```
- (CGFloat)tableViewHeight
{
   [tableView layoutIfNeeded];
   return [tableView contentSize].height;
}
```